# Date function returning incorrect result

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I cannot find an equivalent answer that resolves for me [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304157/swift-reading-date-incorrectly)

Please see the code. I'm formatting an incoming string (item[9]) downloaded from a webservice.

```
var cal_end_date: Date!
```

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

```
let tempEndDate = item[9]

print("item[9]", item[9]) // 20190331
print("tempEndDate", tempEndDate) //20190331

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYYMMDD"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

cal_end_date = dateFormatter.date(from:tempEndDate)!
print(#function, "cal_end_date:", cal_end_date!) //2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000
```

The end date has the wrong month! I have confirmed this result by running the code in a playground with a fixed date. Am I doing something wrong here? Has something changed in Swift 5?
Thanks

Comment: DateFormat is case sensitive. Check it carefully: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` is the needed format.

Comment: and thanks for the date format correction. That worked of course.

Comment: my old brain is malfunctioning. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [nsdateformatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com) to check if your `dateFormat` for your formatter is correct (next to the *Examples* check *Reference* which shows you what each letter/letters represent).

In your case, you have to be carefull on `dateFormat`'s case sensitive. Days and years are represented by small letters

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
```